# AngularJs ng-repeat track by $index issue with angular-bootstrap-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am having an issue with [AngularJs ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) and [angular-bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-switch)

I am using:

```
ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"
```

When I added a new item into the first index of array by:

```
newItem = {};    
items.splice(0, 0, newItem);
```

The DOM contain a bs-switch:
[image]
When a new item added it reuse the first element in array base on $index, so it doesn't re-render ([that's what I get from this docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)). The problem I have is the previous element has *switch-on*.

The DOM effect issue I have is the class "*switch-on*" doesn't refresh on new item and it keep on.

**Expected:** In this case I want to switch is off instead of on like the image. Cause it's an empty object

**P/s:** Cause of the business so

- I cannot add default value for that **Switch**. It need to be an empty object
- I also cannot use any identifier of the item object to track replace to $index
- If I use default track by $id it will cause some business issue also

**TEMP SOLUTION FOR WHO WORKING ON Angular 1.5 or Upper:**

With angular 1.5 and you can use [angular-bootstrap-switch 0.5.1](https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-switch/tree/0.5.2)

It will fixed the issue, after frapontillo release a changed: "**Make "switch-change" trigger when model changes**"

Thank you so much for supporting.

Comment: The temp solution should be an answer, not an edit to the question and should be on the original question, not the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

What I perceive from your question is that you want to add a new item to main array and when It renders, you want it's switch to be **off** by default.

Well there are couple of things you need to keep in mind.

1. `ng-repeat` only behaves as a loop in our DOM.
2. If you want to have the switch off by default, you must need to have a model for that in every item of the main array. It'll keep track of every switch's state in DOM.

Here's what you should try

From your controller:

```
newItem = {switchState: 0};    
items.splice(0, 0, newItem);
```

From your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
<!-- your Name and Decription input fields.. -->

<input
    bs-switch
    ng-model="item.switchState" />
```

So I think you're ignoring `ng-model` of angular-bootstrap-switch which causes you the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.
But cause I cannot set default value for that item, I have mentions before:
"I cannot add default value for that Switch. It need to be an empty object". So
ng-model doesn't help this time. I think.